# Extrude with exact measurements

Tags: mesh

I want to build this thing, *exactly*.

[image]

I've created a cylinder and extrude it.

[image]

How can I extrude the ring outwards exactly 7mm?
Or Is this the complete wrong way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. place a plane or other object exactly 7mm away from your cylinder
2. extrude your ring of faces then scale them in the X/Y plane only with Snap to Vertex enabled and snap them to the object created in 1. Make sure the vertex is what's exactly 7mm away from the cylinder.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Another way to do this is to first create a one-sided cross-section with the object origin in the middle. That way you can extrude with numerical input or even set the locations in the transform panel.

[image]

when all edge lengths and positions match, just use the Screw Modifier or the Spin tool to create the cylinder.

[image]

To me, this method is the most transparent. I have full overview over the shape and dimensions. I usually take my calipers and make a quick drawing on paper to have a reference instead of switching back and forth between object and computer.

It also liberates from the pretty much relative nature of extrusion. I could just measure the distance between the two rims and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>-<kbd>D</kbd> the verts that distance apart. Lots of possibilities.

Comment: +1 for suggesting an alternate workflow which in this case (an object which is almost entirely a SoR) might be a much easier approach

Answer (score 7):

Alt+E >Extrude Region (Vertex normals)

Type "0.007" or "=7mm", Enter

[image]

Comment: Could you please explain how extrusion is  kept in the XY plane? I get 45 degree vertex normals on ngon edge verts. http://pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=128580

Comment: Extrude Region (Vertex normals) is just Blender way to say "Extrude along face normals), I think.

Comment: @batFINGER Extrude scale shift Z would work too on a circular faceloop.

Answer (score 4):

**Calculate scale factor from dimensions**

Consider you have a cylinder with diameter `20cm` (`200mm`).

[image]
 To extrude the selection about centre point, and to have a new diameter of `214mm`  <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>1</kbd>  The 1 is arbitrary we can fix in the operator panel

The required scale factor is `214 / 200` or `1.07`.  Can set the `x`, `y` and `z` scale factor in panel.  (Or <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>S</kbd><kbd>1.07</kbd> and reset `z` to 1.

Notice you can type arithmetic, `214 / 200` directly into the property.

[image]